# How to convert a range subset of bits in a C++ bitset to a number?

Tags: c++, bitset, std-bitset

I have an `std::bitset` and the bitset type also provides a `to_ulong` method to translate the bitset into a number, my problem is about translating the bitset into a number while just considering a range in that bitset, I need to implement my own powerof2 function or there is something with a more standard approach ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can drop the unnecessary bits like

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

// drop bits outside the range [R, L) == [R, L - 1]
template<std::size_t R, std::size_t L, std::size_t N>
std::bitset<N> project_range(std::bitset<N> b)
{
    static_assert(R <= L && L <= N, "invalid bitrange");
    b >>= R;            // drop R rightmost bits
    b <<= (N - L + R);  // drop L-1 leftmost bits
    b >>= (N - L);      // shift back into place
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    std::bitset<8> b2(42); // [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
    std::cout << project_range<0,8>(b2).to_ulong() << "\n"; // 42 == entire bitset
    std::cout << project_range<2,5>(b2).to_ulong() << "\n"; // 8, only middle bit
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=86fe26304d52726b3ddab422f93a99ec-ce6b7b81d29c30e32c78aebe6e642254) with output.

Comment: @user2485710 I made some mistakes in the original version. This one is tested, see the live example.

Comment: wait, doesn't work for me, in this case http://ideone.com/RNJXNH my program should print 15, it prints 120 because it doesn't drop the rightmost bits ...

Comment: @user2485710 bits [3, 7) *as a subset of [0,32)* represents 120, if you rightshift that another 3 bits, you get 15. If that is the behavior you want, simply change the last statement to: `b >>= (num - l + r);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string` as intermediate storage:

```
bitset<32> bs (string("1011"));
cout << bs.to_ullong() << endl;

// take a range - 2 last bits in this case
string s = bs.to_string().substr(bs.size() - 2);  

bitset<32> bs1 (s);
cout << bs1.to_ullong() << endl;
```

Prints:

```
11
3
```

Comment: nice to have options, but I think that this creates unnecessary temporary variables . I need to shrink my steps into a very small number.